# Infinite Loop React

Tags: reactjs, loops, axios

I'm new in React, and i have problems to show the content of an array.
I have a state to store the data (initial value []). Then, I have a function to consume frmo an api with a get, then i store that data in the state, and finally, I iterate over the state to show it on the page. Everything's is ok, the function gives return the values, but in the console, the return is enter in a infinite loop, slowing down the browser.

Here I detach the code

The state where i store the values

```
const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
```

Function that consumes the api and save it in the state

```
const getData = async () => {
let allProjects = {};
const res = await axios.get(URL_BASE);
allProjects = res.data;
setProjects(allProjects);
console.log(projects);
};
```

useEffect to refresh the render when projects is change

```
useEffect(() => {
getData();
}, [projects]);
```

This is where i iterate

```
return (
<div>
  <p>La cantidadd de proyectos en total son:</p>
  {getData() && projects.map((proyecto) => <div>{proyecto.titulo}</div>)}
</div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This `useEffect` basically says "any time `projects` changes, run `getData()`":

```
useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, [projects]);
```

And running `getData()` *changes `projects`*:

```
const getData = async () => {
  //...
  setProjects(allProjects);
  //...
};
```

Thus the endless cycle.

It sounds like you just want to `getData()` once, when the component first loads.  For that you can just use an empty dependency array:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getData();
}, []);
```